# Angular 4: Subscribing to Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a project that required clients (not users but more like customers) to be loaded and selected.

Unfortunately I can't seem to subscribe to the Observables I am loading in my component. I have tried every possible solution I could find online but perhaps my inexperience with Angular is preventing me from finding the right one.

What is working right now:
- loading clients in select box
- giving value of client' id to option in select box
- sending client's id to client.service and saving the selected client as an Observable

So my only problem is that the component doesn't notice change in the Observables in client.service.

Here is my client.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Client } from './client';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Injectable()
export class ClientService {

    clients$: Observable<Client[]>;
    client: Client;
    selectedClient$: Observable<Client[]>;

    constructor(private api: ApiService) {
        this.clients$ = this.getAll();
    }

    public getAll(): Observable<Client[]> {
        return this.api.get<Client[]>('clients');
    }

    public setSelectedClient(clientId: number) {
        this.clients$ = this.getAll();
        if (clientId == null) {
            // Do nothing
        } else {
            this.selectedClient$ = this.clients$.map(arr =>
            { return arr.find(client => client.id === clientId) });
        }
    }

    public getSelectedClient() : Observable<Client> {
        return this.selectedClient$;
    }

}
```

My component, with commented bits to show some attempts at fixing my problem:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { ClientService } from "../client/client.service";
import { Client } from "../client/client";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-left-menu',
    templateUrl: './left-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./left-menu.component.css']
})

export class LeftMenuComponent implements OnInit {

    selectedClient$ : Observable<Client>;
    client: Client = new Client();
    clients$ : Observable<Client[]>;

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // this.clientService.getSelectedClient().subscribe(selectedClient$ => {
        //     this.selectedClient$ = Observable.of(selectedClient$);
        // });
        // //
        // this.clientService.getAll().subscribe(clients$ => {
        //     this.clients$ = Observable.of(clients$);
        // });

        this.selectedClient$ = this.clientService.getSelectedClient();
        this.clients$ = this.clientService.getAll();
    }

    public setSelectedClient(clientId: number) {
        this.clientService.setSelectedClient(clientId);
    }

}
```

And the part of html I use to display and select a client:

```
 <select #selectClient [ngModel]="selectedClient$ | async" 
   (ngModelChange)="setSelectedClient(selectClient.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let client of clients$ | async" [value]="client.id">
            {{ client.firstName }}
            {{ client.preposition }}
            {{ client.lastName }}
        </option>
 </select>

 <!-- Displaying selected client -->
 <h2 *ngIf="selectedClient$">{{(selectedClient$ | async)?.firstName}}
 </h2>
```

If anyone could help me out with this it would be MUCH appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I assume your `ApiService`'s `get<Client[]>()` method is based on angular's built in `HttpModule`/`HttpClientModule`, right?

Comment: This is the get method in the ApiService, clients in my case aren't users (I will change it to customers in my question to be more clear): public get <T>(path: string, queryParameters?: Object): Observable<T> {
        let uri = this.createURI(path, queryParameters);
        let headers = this.createRequestHeaders();

        return this.http.get<T>(uri, { headers: headers });
    }

Comment: Never mind my question, I just realized it's not relevant to the answer, sorry :)

Comment: do you use `selectedClient` in other components in the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnq1qa)**

use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]` which let you bind the client object itself to the `[ngModel]` directive, I also used `Subject` to easily notify other subscribers to the new selected client :

client.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { Client } from './client';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {

    clients$: Observable<Client[]>;
    client: Client;
    selectedClient$: Subject<Client> = new Subject<Client>();

    //...
    public setSelectedClient(client: Client) {
        if (client)
            this.selectedClient$.next(client);
    }
    //...
}
```

component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { ClientService } from './client.service';
import { Client } from './client'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

    selectedClient : Client;
    client: Client = new Client();
    clients$ : Observable<Client[]>;

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //...
        this.clients$ = this.clientService.getAll();
        this.clientService.selectedClient$.subscribe(console.log)
    }

    setSelectedClient(client : Client){
      this.selectedClient = client;
      this.clientService.setSelectedClient(client)
    }
}
```

template :

```
<select #selectClient [ngModel]="selectedClient" 
(ngModelChange)="setSelectedClient($event)">
     <option *ngFor="let client of clients$ | async" [ngValue]="client">
         {{ client.firstName }}
         {{ client.preposition }}
         {{ client.lastName }}
     </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. This worked, I can now retrieve attributes of selectedClient in other components as well. I retrieve the attribute like this for anyone who wonders:  <h2 *ngIf="clientService.selectedClient$">{{(clientService.selectedClient$ | async)?.firstName}}</h2>

Comment: Do you think I could use a similar manner to get updates on clients$?

Comment: like this : `<h2 *ngIf="clientService.selectedClient$ | async">`. I didn't understand your last question @MartineMulder

Comment: @MartineMulder yes, I just put it there to check  it works

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the way that you have assigned the `clients$` and `selectedClient$` observable properties to your `LeftMenuComponent`.

The `setSelectedClient()` method on the `ClientService` will change the properties on the service. However, your `LeftMenuComponent`'s `ngOnInit()` only does the assignment of the properties once, and the changes from `setSelectedClient()` won't be reflected on the LeftMenuComponent.

To make this work, you don't need to re-assign the properties onto to component. You could simply bind the properties of the service directly inside your template like this:

```
 <select #selectClient [ngModel]="clientService.selectedClient$ | async" 
   (ngModelChange)="setSelectedClient(selectClient.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let client of clientService.clients$ | async" [value]="client.id">
            {{ client.firstName }}
            {{ client.preposition }}
            {{ client.lastName }}
        </option>
 </select>
```

Another option that might be cleaner is to simply use getter properties on the component instead of the assignment, like this:

```
export class LeftMenuComponent implements OnInit {

    client: Client = new Client();
    get selectedClient$(): Observable<Client> {
        return this.clientService.selectedClient$;
    }
    get clients$(): Observable<Client> {
        return this.clientService.client$;
    }

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // init things, but no assignment needed now
    }
```